# Problems with an encoding batch file

Tags: batch-file, encode

I have been recently working on a batch file that will encode Text. Below is my code but I am running into problems when setting the text I input to encode. I took the idea of this encode batch file from [here](http://scripts.dragon-it.co.uk/scripts.nsf/docs/batch-search-replace-substitute!OpenDocument&ExpandSection=3&BaseTarget=East&AutoFramed).

```
@echo off
Title Cipher
Echo Enter Text To Encode:
Set /p ci=">"
If %ci%==%ci% goto Decode
:Decode
Cls
Echo Decoding...
set string=%ci%
set string=%string:a=1%
set string=%string:b=2%
set string=%string:c=3%
set string=%string:d=4%
set string=%string:e=5%
set string=%string:f=6%
set string=%string:g=7%
set string=%string:h=8%
set string=%string:i=9%
set string=%string:j=A%
set string=%string:k=B%
set string=%string:l=C%
set string=%string:m=D%
set string=%string:n=E%
set string=%string:o=F%
set string=%string:p=G%
set string=%string:q=H%
set string=%string:r=I%
set string=%string:s=J%
set string=%string:t=K%
set string=%string:u=L%
set string=%string:v=M%
set string=%string:w=N%
set string=%string:x=O%
set string=%string:y=P%
set string=%string:z=Q%
set Encode=%string%
Cls
Echo Previous Text: %ci%
Echo.
Echo Encoded To: %Encode%
Ping localhost -n 2 > nul
Echo. 
Echo Copy Code Now!
ping localhost -n 2 > nul
Pause
```

Comment: You haven't revealed what problems you are seeing.

Comment: Are you sure that you replace a character only once?

Comment: The Problem is if i have a Space in my Text that i input to be encoded, it will not accept it. I Just need to know how to Make it encode multiple words at one time.

Answer (score 0):

try this, this allows you to decode and encode

```
@echo off
Title Cipher

:menu
echo   [ menu ]
echo.
echo 1 (Encode)
echo.
echo 2 (decode)
echo.
echo 3 (exit)
set /p choose=">"
if %choose%==1 goto 1
if %choose%==2 goto 2
if %choose%==3 goto exit
goto menu

:1
Echo Enter Text To Encode:
Set /p ci=">"
If %ci%==%ci% goto Decode
:Decode
Cls
Echo Decoding...
ping localhost -n 2 >nul
set string=%ci%
set string=%string:a=1%
set string=%string:b=2%
set string=%string:c=3%
set string=%string:d=4%
set string=%string:e=5%
set string=%string:f=6%
set string=%string:g=7%
set string=%string:h=8%
set string=%string:i=9%
set string=%string:j=A%
set string=%string:k=B%
set string=%string:l=C%
set string=%string:m=D%
set string=%string:n=E%
set string=%string:o=F%
set string=%string:p=G%
set string=%string:q=H%
set string=%string:r=I%
set string=%string:s=J%
set string=%string:t=K%
set string=%string:u=L%
set string=%string:v=M%
set string=%string:w=N%
set string=%string:x=O%
set string=%string:y=P%
set string=%string:z=Q%
set Encode=%string%
Cls
Echo Previous Text: %ci%
Echo.
Echo Encoded To: %Encode%
echo.
echo.
Pause
goto menu

:exit
exit
goto exit

:2
Echo Enter Text To Decode:
Set /p ic=">"
If %ic%==%ic% goto Encode
:Encode
Cls
Echo Encoding...
ping localhost -n 2 >nul
set string=%ic%
set string=%string:Q=z%
set string=%string:P=y%
set string=%string:O=x%
set string=%string:N=w%
set string=%string:M=v%
set string=%string:L=u%
set string=%string:K=t%
set string=%string:J=s%
set string=%string:I=r%
set string=%string:H=q%
set string=%string:G=p%
set string=%string:F=o%
set string=%string:E=n%
set string=%string:D=m%
set string=%string:C=l%
set string=%string:B=k%
set string=%string:A=j%
set string=%string:9=i%
set string=%string:8=h%
set string=%string:7=g%
set string=%string:6=f%
set string=%string:5=e%
set string=%string:4=d%
set string=%string:3=c%
set string=%string:2=b%
set string=%string:1=a%
set Encode=%string%
Cls
Echo Previous Text: %ic%
Echo.
Echo Encoded To: %Encode%
echo.
echo.
Pause
goto menu
```

Answer (score 0):

this is to encode with multiple words in a sentence

```
@echo off
Echo Enter Text To Encode:
Set /p ci=">"
If "%ci%"=="%ci%" goto Decode
:Decode
Cls
Echo Decoding...
ping localhost -n 2 >nul
set string="%ci%"
set string=%string:a=1%
set string=%string:b=2%
set string=%string:c=3%
set string=%string:d=4%
set string=%string:e=5%
set string=%string:f=6%
set string=%string:g=7%
set string=%string:h=8%
set string=%string:i=9%
set string=%string:j=A%
set string=%string:k=B%
set string=%string:l=C%
set string=%string:m=D%
set string=%string:n=E%
set string=%string:o=F%
set string=%string:p=G%
set string=%string:q=H%
set string=%string:r=I%
set string=%string:s=J%
set string=%string:t=K%
set string=%string:u=L%
set string=%string:v=M%
set string=%string:w=N%
set string=%string:x=O%
set string=%string:y=P%
set string=%string:z=Q%
set string=%string:"= %
set Encode=%string%
Cls
Echo Previous Text: "%ci%"
Echo.
Echo Encoded To: %Encode%
echo.
echo.
Pause
exit
```